Access to cvat events from nuclio function
I have deployed a model using this tutorial (Python): https://docs.cvat.ai/docs/manual/advanced/serverless-tutorial/
All works fine. Now I would like to connect my model (nuclio function) with linear interpolation with one point (https://docs.cvat.ai/docs/manual/advanced/annotation-with-points/liner-interpolation-with-one-point/).
I would like to be able to receive points annotated by user and pass it to my model.

How to handle events from cvat (cvat-ui?) (for example: user created keyframe) inside nuclio function?
How to call my nuclio function for all intermediate frames that are used for linear point interpolation?

Thank you!
One possible solution is to deploy another nuclio funcion that implements linear point interpolation and call the function with model from it. But I dont want to implement something that already integrated in CVAT.
